# cant set html string to with breakLine to TextArea in ASp.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Tinymcy in asp.net mvc project. 
In edit Action I using this code to set Featched text from database to textarea.

```
 editorSetHtml('@(Html.Raw(Model.Body))');  //*

 var editorSetHtml = function (html) {
    tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(html);

}
```

but the `*` line returns `SyntaxError` :

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

and in debugger I have this :

> editorSetHtml('<p>one</p>
>   <p>two</p>');

the data in database is Like :
[image]

how can I solve this ?

Comment: can you try to implement like tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(html, {format : 'raw'});

Comment: Can you provide your actually code? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like to me the '<p>one</p> <p>two</p>' isn't what caused the error. What is causing the error is most likely something to do with forgetting to escape a character, or something similar. If you could provide your actual code (if this one isn't), I might be able to provide a solution

Comment: @TheAssassinSpy yes , its `<p>one</p> <p>two</p>` how can I escape  ?

Comment: @workquestion Now is where things get weird. Usually what happens is that there is something like "<a href="myLink"></a>" and people forget to put "\" in front of the inner double quotes, but that is not the case here. If I am correct, the data in the database is exactly '<p>one</p> <p>two</p>'? No double quotes and such? Also, is it possible to send me a full copy of your code to test/try to fix? It would be really helpful.

Comment: I have got error when I have `BreakLine` in text Editor . when I have something like `a< href="">aaa</a>` its ok and works fine

Comment: What is the error that you get and what did you do to make it happen?